# Is there any program to push files to my Android phone?

Tags: android, transfer

I'm looking for an application on my Ubuntu desktop that will allow me to push files to my Android phone.

Ideally, the syntax would be something like this:

```
push2phone screenshot_1.jpg
```

and my phone would then receive this file automatically. I am aware of solutions like syncthing and FTP servers, but the first program requires me to run daemons on both laptop and phone for a simple file transfer. The FTP server is also a hassle because I have to start a FTP server before doing the transfer, find out the correct IP address, and then open this directory on my computer.

Comment: Umm... [ADB](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-customization-transfer-files-adb-push-adb-pull-601015/)?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this.

### MTP

Connect your phone to your computer using a USB cable. Your phone should prompt you to select a transfer mode.  Select MTP or File Transfer.

Ubuntu should then mount your phone like a regular USB device.

On the command line, you can use `cp` or `mv` to transfer files.

### ADB

Install the [Android Debug Bridge from Google](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip) or by using `sudo apt install android-tools-adbd`

If your phone is in developer mode, when you plug it into your computer the phone should prompt you to trust the computer.

You can then use `adb push screenshot_1.jpg /path/on/your/phone`